# PermGen Space issue in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, hudson

I am building a maven project, since last 1.5 yrs build was working fine but now I am getting the PermGen space error.

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed: java.io.IOException: Remote call on channel failed: PermGen space -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I have tried below options in order to resolve it:-

1) Under ***Manage Jenkins***, then ***Configure System***. In the ***Global properties*** section, added ***Environment Variables*** called MAVEN_OPTS with the value set as `-Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

2) Under ***job configuration***, then ***Build***, in the ***MAVEN_OPTS***, added below properties:-

```
-DXms512m
-DXmx1024m
-DXX:PermSize=512m
-DXX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-DXX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-DXX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Still the error is occurring.

**Note:-** Error is not permanent, it goes away after few builds but again start appearing and then again goes away after several retries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems that your memory error happens when Jenkins try to send the build information to Artifactory (with a post step action).

Did you upgrade the Jenkins Artifactory plugin recently?

Can you try do disable the "Capture and publish build info" option?

[image]

And last option, can you try update the JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS (in the jenkins service config file) to increase the MaxPermSize?

```
## Type: string
## Default:     "-Djava.awt.headless=true"
## ServiceRestart: jenkins
#
# Options to pass to java when running Jenkins.
#
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms2G -Xmx4G -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, yes the build fails when it tries to deploy artifact to artifactory.
I have disabled "Capture and publish build info" option but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you activate this option? --> Enable JIRA Integration

Comment: Did you set some JAVA arguments in Jenkins startup script? It can help to solve your issue :)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, yes the build fails when it tries to deploy artifact to artifactory.
I have disabled "Capture and publish build info" option but it doesn't work.

I am not able to find the jenkins config file as well on the server. There is no file named jenkins.xml or jenkins.config. It is not present neither in /etc/default/jenkins  nor in /etc/sysconfig/

This is disabled Enable JIRA Integration

Comment: Your path for the config file seems correct (/etc/default/jenkins for Ubuntu and /etc/sysconfig/jenkins for CentOS). Are you connected with the root account or with a user (with sudo permissions)?

Answer (score 0):

As Maven project deploys artifacts **not** during build step on a **node**, but on the **master**, I suspect Permgen problem could by resolved by either upgrading Jenkins core, plugins or by increasing Permgen max size in Jenkins startup options.

ps. Java 8 obsoletes Permgen.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am blind and you have written it somewhere but when I have faced a similar issue, then I have upgraded the JRE version for Jenkins itself from 7 to 8. The problem started, when I have used Jenkins 2.X and Java 7.

Best regards,

Max

Answer (score 0):

on centos6 install jenkins by rpm or yum

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins
JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```